# Django Rest Framework creating profile for custom user error:'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I made a custom user,with knox authentication and I want to create a profile for each user,
here is what i have for profile model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    GENDER = (
        ('M','Male'),
        ('F','Female'),
    )
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER,blank=True)

    def create(self,user,username):
        self.user=user
        self.username = username
        return self
```

Serializers

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','username','email','phone_number')

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','username','email','phone_number','password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password':{'write_only':True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            **validated_data
        )
        username = validated_data['username']
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user,username=username)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        return user,profile

class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        user = authenticate(**data)
        if user and user.is_active:
            return user
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Incorrect Credentials')

#serializer for profile
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['username','gender']

    username = serializers.CharField(source='User.username')
```

and this for views

```
class UserApiView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user

class RegisterApiView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data = request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user,profile = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            'user': UserSerializer(user,context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            'token':AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1],
            'profile':ProfileSerializer(profile,context=self.get_serializer_context()).data
        })

class LoginApiView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })

class ProfileApiView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        return Response({
            "username":ProfileSerializer(context=self.get_serializer_context()).data
        })
```

Also,I'm relatively new to drf and django in general,and I was wondering if someone could suggest a better practice to make a profile for each user at the moment of registration.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
I tryed to do the following:

```
user,profile = serializer.save()
```

and it produces the following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bragdon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Bragdon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Bragdon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bragdon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bragdon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bragdon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Bragdon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Bragdon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Bragdon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bragdon\PycharmProjects\version1\users\api\views.py", line 24, in post
    'profile':ProfileSerializer(profile,context=self.get_serializer_context()).data
  File "C:\Users\Bragdon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 562, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "C:\Users\Bragdon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 260, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "C:\Users\Bragdon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 516, in to_representation
    attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Bragdon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 487, in get_attribute
    raise type(exc)(msg)
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `username` on serializer `ProfileSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Profile` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'User'.
```

Comment: Can you share the traceback?

Comment: You're calling `serializer.save()` twice, could this be your issue?

Comment: That's right,what should I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Here, `serailizer.save()` is returning tuple (`User` object, `Profile` object). So,  Remove duplicate `serializer.save()` from `RegisterApiView`. Instead, do the following.

   ```
   user, profile = serializer.save()
   ```
2. Change `source="User.username"` to `source="user.username"` at `ProfileSerializer`

   ```
   username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The `create` method returns `user, profile`, you can just call this method once and assign both `user` and `profile` using tuple unpacking

```
user, profile = serializer.create(serializer.validated_data)
```

Comment: I tryed this line,and it still produces AttributeError